# Need help making WPF application update UI asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I'm having trouble making my ComputeListener function work as expected.

I want the `StatusBlock.Text` to be immediately updated on the UI even before **Compute()** begins, but I cannot get this to work.

I know this question has been asked elsewhere on StackOverflow, but none of the solutions that I saw worked for me.

I've dealt with several problems along the way, but the current issue is that no changes are made until **ComputeListener()** has fully completed its execution and all other features are locked until then.

I want to also be able to click the close button to stop the application if Compute() is taking too long, but this cannot happen either.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ComputeListener(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { StatusBlock.Text = "Status: Processing"; })));
        t.Wait();
        Task.Run(() => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Compute(); })));
    }
    private void Compute()
    {
       //code here
    }
```

Comment: I guess you would like to be looking into the async / await pattern, since you use tasks, but you are not awaiting them and your function isn't marked async

Comment: @Icepickle. Yeah, you're right, that's what I needed to do--I didn't really know how async functions worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've correctly identified that executing `Compute()` on the UI thread will stop the `StatusBlock.Text` change from reflecting in the UI as desired, and that `Task` should be used.

However you get cross-thread exceptions trying to update the UI from a worker thread, so you've used the `Window.Dispatcher` to get back on the UI thread.

As Icepickle recommends - you want `async`/`await` here. I think the following should work:

```cs
    public async void ComputeListener(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        StatusBlock.Text = "Status: Processing";
        await Task.Run(() => Compute());
    }

    private void Compute()
    {
       //code here
    }
```

Or even better:

```cs
    public async void ComputeListener(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        StatusBlock.Text = "Status: Processing";
        await ComputeAsync();
    }

    private async Task ComputeAsync()
    {
       //async code here
    }
```

**Note** if your implementation of `Compute()` also needs access to the UI, you'll still run into issues with this - this is a code smell as your business logic (i.e. computation) should be independent of the WPF front-end.

I'd recommend moving towards an MVVM approach - this [Xamarin.Forms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) explains the general concepts well, which can be applied to WPF in much the same way

Comment: Perfect--it works like a charm! Thanks for the help and I'll do some research into the topics you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the asynchronous dispatcher member `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` instead of wrapping it into a `Task`.

`Task.Run` is always awaitable to execute it asynchronously. `Task.Wait()` contradicts the idea as it forces the `Task` to execute synchronously, since it is blocking the thread until the `Task` has completed, cancelled or faulted. Read the remarks of Microsoft Docs: [`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait). When used in combination with `Task.Run` chances are high for introducing a deadlock. So always avoid `Task.Wait` and use the asynchronous and awaitable versions `Task.WaitAny` and `Task.WaitAll` if you need to join multiple `Task` instances.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public async void ComputeListener(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
  {
    // Don't block while waiting for Dispatcher to execute the action
    await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => StatusBlock.Text = "Status: Processing");

    // Executes asynchronously on a background thread (thread pool thread).
    // Use for CPU bound operations
    await ComputeOnNewBackgroundThreadAsync();

    // Executes asynchronously on the current thread.
    // Use for lightweight async operations 
    Task task = new Task(ComputeOnCurrentUiThread);
    task.Start();
    await task;

    // Waiting for tasks example
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    Task currentThreadTask = new Task(ComputeOnCurrentUiThread);
    currentThreadTask.Start();
    tasks.Add(currentThreadTask);

    Task backgroundThreadTask = ComputeOnNewBackgroundThreadAsync();
    tasks.Add(backgroundThreadTask);

    // Wait asynchronously for both Task instances to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  }

  private async Task ComputeOnNewBackgroundThreadAsync()
  {
    await Task.Run(
      () =>
      {
        //code here
      });
  }

  private void ComputeOnCurrentUiThread()
  {
    //code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was trying something pretty similar to this at one point, but I guess I didn't do it quite right.